# Restrict restarting systemd service with timer assigned

Tags: java, ansible, continuous-integration, systemd

I have a systemd service unit with `OnCalendar` timer assigned to it. That service invokes JVM, which runs code, that has to be started only on a specific schedule.

This systemd unit (and several others) are managed by the ansible playbook, which uses  [openstack/ansible-role-systemd_service](https://github.com/openstack/ansible-role-systemd_service) role. It restarts systemd services every time I make some changes in their unit files.

Also, there's a handler, which restarts all the services every time Gitlab CI pipeline runs this ansible playbook and uploads a new `.jar` artifact to a server.

**Is there any systemd built-in mechanism to restrict restarting service with timer assigned to it?** Still, I have to be able to stop/start those services manually when it's needed.

Seems like I can fork that ansible role and add some check, but I wonder for some native and more straight-forward way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can put `RefuseManualStart=yes` `RefuseManualStop=yes` in timer and service units.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I want to be able to start/stop services manually when it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I've found the way:

**Create** and **don't enable** `.service` unit, that would contain next:

```
[Unit]
After = network-online.target
...

[Service]
Type = simple
...
SuccessExitStatus = 143
RestartForceExitStatus = 143
Restart = on-failure
RemainAfterExit = False
StandardOutput = null
StandardError = syslog

[̶I̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶]
W̶a̶n̶t̶e̶d̶B̶y̶ ̶=̶ ̶m̶u̶l̶t̶i̶-̶u̶s̶e̶r̶.̶t̶a̶r̶g̶e̶t̶
```

**Create** and **enable** `.timer` unit, that would contain next:

```
[Timer]
O̶n̶B̶o̶o̶t̶S̶e̶c̶ ̶=̶ ̶0̶m̶i̶n̶
OnCalendar = *-*-* 18:00:00
Persistent = yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

A little explanation:

```
After = network-online.target
```

Needed to make sure that service would start only after getting online.

```
Restart = on-failure
SuccessExitStatus = 143
RestartForceExitStatus = 143
```

Needed to be able to `kill` the main process and make systemd restart the service, or stop the service w/o systemd marking it `failed`. It's because JVM returning 143 exit code when the main process receives `SIGTERM` and stops gracefully.

```
RemainAfterExit = False
```

Needed for `.timer` to understand that `.service` stoped. Either way, `.timer` would hang in the `running` state, and won't run service next time.

```
StandardOutput = null
StandardError = syslog
```

Needed to stop the main process from writing its INFO log to syslog, and write there only ERRORs.

```
[̶I̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶]
W̶a̶n̶t̶e̶d̶B̶y̶ ̶=̶ ̶m̶u̶l̶t̶i̶-̶u̶s̶e̶r̶.̶t̶a̶r̶g̶e̶t̶
```

Omitted cause the service has to be disabled. Either way, it would be stared on system boot.

```
Persistent = yes
```

Needed to be able to start service later that day after system boot, if the target time was missed.

```
O̶n̶B̶o̶o̶t̶S̶e̶c̶ ̶=̶ ̶0̶m̶i̶n̶
```

Omitted cause `OnCalendar` was used.

All those changes seem to have done the trick.